# I got an error while converting from py to exe

Tags: python

I got an error while converting from py to exe. While running py, still run normally
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBMO8.png)

Comment: Please include the full error message in your question instead of linking to it, and explain what you are trying to accomplish with detail.

Comment: Please add the entire error description in the post instead of link. Links can be broken in future. And also add more details on what you are trying to do.